# Do Garmin InReach plans include unlimited incoming messages?

Tags: communication, satellite-phones

I am considering getting a Garmin InReach device (a device allowing two-way satellite communication via text messages) and I am trying to decipher the hidden costs of the subscription that comes along.

If I understand correctly how it works, the communication is possible by sending a message to a regular phone number, to an email, to another InReach device. In the case where I send an email to some friends or family members, I assume they can reply for free.

The [subscription page](https://explore.garmin.com/en-CA/inreach/#subscriptions) lists the pricing for sending a different kinds of messages and receiving the weather forecast, but it never mentions a price for receiving messages, nor does the help section of the website.

When I use an InReach device, is there any cost when I receive a message, either for me or for the sender?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Incoming messages count against the limit of text messages.

> Yes, **any message sent back to your inReach device**, including replies to preset messages, **count against your monthly message allotment.**

[Source](https://support.garmin.com/en-US/?faq=Dlq83lU2Ru5SHas9vohbbA#7)

But it will not cost the person sending you a message.

Comment: My understanding as well. I’ll know more when my first bill comes in a bit...